# tensorflow - tf.cond does not work if predicate is passed from function

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

The code below somehow always goes to `do_not_come_here`. I suppose the usage `tf.cond` in the function `g` is not correct but not sure how to fix. Please advise.

### Code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds


def do_not_come_here(image, flag):
    tf.print(flag)
    tf.assert_equal(0, 1)   

def g(image, flag):
    tf.cond(
        pred=flag,             # same with pred=tf.math.equal(flag, tf.constant(True))
        true_fn=lambda: image,
        false_fn=lambda: do_not_come_here(image, flag)
    )

def f(record):
    image = record['image']
    g(image, tf.constant(True))

train, info = tfds.load("voc", split='train', with_info=True)
train.take(1).flat_map(f)   # same with .map(f)
```

### Stacktrace

```
~/venv/ml/bin/python ~/reproduction.py 
2023-11-20 17:19:25.390562: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:111] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable `TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0`.
2023-11-20 17:19:25.415972: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9342] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2023-11-20 17:19:25.415993: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:609] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2023-11-20 17:19:25.416010: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1518] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2023-11-20 17:19:25.420375: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 AVX_VNNI FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-11-20 17:19:26.669052: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:894] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-11-20 17:19:26.672374: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:894] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-11-20 17:19:26.672502: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:894] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-11-20 17:19:26.673349: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:894] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-11-20 17:19:26.673435: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:894] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-11-20 17:19:26.673493: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:894] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-11-20 17:19:26.729836: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:894] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-11-20 17:19:26.729955: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:894] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-11-20 17:19:26.730043: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:894] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero. See more at https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/Documentation/ABI/testing/sysfs-bus-pci#L344-L355
2023-11-20 17:19:26.730112: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1886] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1228 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4050 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/reproduction.py", line 21, in <module>
    train.take(1).flat_map(f)
  File "~/venv/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 2313, in flat_map
    return flat_map_op._flat_map(self, map_func, name=name)
  File "~/venv/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/flat_map_op.py", line 24, in _flat_map
    return _FlatMapDataset(input_dataset, map_func, name)
  File "~/venv/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/flat_map_op.py", line 33, in __init__
    self._map_func = structured_function.StructuredFunctionWrapper(
  File "~/venv/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/structured_function.py", line 265, in __init__
    self._function = fn_factory()
  File "~/venv/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py", line 1222, in get_concrete_function
    concrete = self._get_concrete_function_garbage_collected(*args, **kwargs)
  File "~/venv/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py", line 1192, in _get_concrete_function_garbage_collected
    self._initialize(args, kwargs, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "~/venv/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py", line 694, in _initialize
    self._concrete_variable_creation_fn = tracing_compilation.trace_function(
  File "~/venv/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compilation.py", line 178, in trace_function
    concrete_function = _maybe_define_function(
  File "~/venv/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compilation.py", line 284, in _maybe_define_function
    concrete_function = _create_concrete_function(
  File "~/venv/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/tracing_compilation.py", line 308, in _create_concrete_function
    traced_func_graph = func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "~/venv/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1059, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "~/venv/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/polymorphic_function.py", line 597, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "~/venv/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/structured_function.py", line 231, in wrapped_fn
    ret = wrapper_helper(*args)
  File "~/venv/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/structured_function.py", line 161, in wrapper_helper
    ret = autograph.tf_convert(self._func, ag_ctx)(*nested_args)
  File "~/venv/ml/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py", line 693, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: in user code:

    File "~/reproduction.py", line 18, in f  *
        g(image, tf.constant(True))
    File "~/reproduction.py", line 10, in g  *
        tf.cond(
    File "~/reproduction.py", line 7, in do_not_come_here  *
        tf.assert_equal(0, 1)

    InvalidArgumentError: Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:
    x (cond/assert_equal_1/x:0) = 
    0
    y (cond/assert_equal_1/y:0) = 
    1


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Same symptom with:

```
def g(image, flag):
    tf.cond(
        pred=tf.math.equal(flag, tf.constant(1)),
        true_fn=lambda: image,
        false_fn=lambda: do_not_come_here(image, flag)
    )

def f(record):
    image = record['image']
    g(image, tf.constant(1))
```

Same symptom with:

```
def g(image, flag):
    tf.cond(
        pred=tf.math.equal(flag, tf.constant(1)),       
        true_fn=lambda: do_not_come_here(image, flag), # <--- swap true_fn with false_fn
        false_fn=lambda: image
    )

def f(record):
    image = record['image']
    g(image, tf.constant(1))
```

### Environment

```
Python 3.10.12
tensorflow                   2.14.1
tensorflow-datasets          4.9.3
NAME="Pop!_OS" VERSION="22.04 LTS"
```

Comment: The `tf.cond` behaves different in eager mode and graph mode. In above case, it runs in graph mode and tries to evaluate both branch (true and false) in runtime and therefore hits the assert.

Comment: If it's clear the purpose of `do_not_come_here`, it would be helpful to find a solution.

Comment: report on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues